# How do I extract a value from a time formatted value in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

**How do I extract a value from a time formatted value in excel?**

On the values below

column1 - is in this format => hh:mm:ss.000 
column2 - is the decimal value of the  
column3 - is = to column2 but I have formatted that hh:mm:ss.000

[image]

I want to be able to extract the 5 or 005 from the column 3 above. How do I do this? 
To get the hour, minute, or second, I can use the hour, minute, or second functions respectively. 
**But how do I extract the thousand second e.g. .005 in this case?**

**NOTE:**
1 second =  1.15741E-05(=1/86400)
0.005*(1/86400) = 0.00000005787 = the decimal presentation of 5 thousand of a second(0.005). All I need to do is change the format of the cell to `hh:mm:ss.000` to present it differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a time in cell **A1**, use:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.000"),3)
```

yields milliseconds as text, and if you need it as a number:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.000"),3)*1
```

*(the second formula gives the number of milliseconds as an **integer**)*

Similar formulas can capture hours or minutes or seconds as integers.

Answer (score 3):

This will return the fraction of the seconds as an integer:

```
=MOD(A1*86400,1)*1000
```

The Mod removes everything but the fraction of the second and the `* 1000` causes it to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are lots of neat ways to do this.  Here is another:

```
=(B8-TIME(HOUR(B8),MINUTE(B8),SECOND(B8)))*86400*1000
```

Where time is in cell B8.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the result to be `0.005` as a number

Your best bet may be to extract the fractions of a second as a string and convert that to a number. This should do it:

```
=VALUE("0." & RIGHT(TEXT(E5,"hh:mm:ss.000"),LEN(TEXT(E5,"hh:mm:ss.000"))-FIND(".",TEXT(E5,"hh:mm:ss.000"))))
```